# Ist irgendwo nachzuschlagen, mit welchem Adjektiv ein Substantiv "gemessen" wird (ist eine Geschwindigkeit hoch oder groß oder beides)?

Tags: word-choice, resource

Manchmal wissen auch einige von uns Muttersprachlern nicht genau, mit welchem Adjektiv ein Substantiv steht; ob eine Geschwindigkeit *hoch* oder *groß* ist, oder ob ein Adjektiv vielleicht nicht passt: Darf z. B. eine Landschaft *hübsch* sein?

Gibt es eine Systematik? Wo kann eine Deutsch lernende Person so etwas nachschlagen? Und ist derlei überhaupt geregelt oder "darf" ich das verwenden wie ich will und spreche immer noch korrektes Deutsch?

Comment: die Frage gefällt mir :)... bezüglich der letzten Frage: ich bin der meinug, dass man, solange man verstanden wird und dem Gesprächspartner nichts negativ auffällt, korrektes Deutsch spricht. Adjektiv-Substantiv Kombis können mehr oder minder fixe Pattern sein. Je fixer desto eher fällt es negativ auf. Allerdings sind da die Grenzen fließend und stark regional bedingt. Ich denke nicht, dass sich jemand jemals die Arbeit gemacht hat, zu dokumentieren oder festzulegen, was Hochdeutsch "korrekt" ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass es irgendwo eine "offizielle" Liste "erlaubter" Adjektiv-Substantiv-Kombinationen gibt, allein schon aus logistischen Gründen - da dürften ja doch einige Millionen bis Milliarden Kombinationen vorkommen, selbst wenn man nur 1:1-Kombinationen erfasst.

Abgesehen davon macht die Dynamik einer lebendigen Sprache, insbesondere in Zeiten des Internets, jegliche solcher Listen innerhalb kürzester Zeit zumindest teilweise hinfällig. Nimmt man noch die Kunstfreiheit dazu, die vor allem in der Lyrik/Poesie praktiziert wird, grundsätzlich aber natürlich jedem zusteht, dann kann man, so mein Bauchgefühl, praktisch jede Kombination "rechtfertigen".

Ob der Kommunikationspartner mit dem so Gesprochenen/Geschriebenen dann etwas anfangen kann, ist eine Frage, die vermutlich keine Regel jemals wird erfassen können.

Die beste Methode, um die "Legalität", oder besser: Verständlichkeit einer bestimmten Kombination herauszufinden, kann m. E. nur statistischer Natur sein; im einfachsten Fall eine Suche auf Google im web oder auf [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: Die Frage, wie viele Kombinationen es gibt, ist interessant und keineswegs trivial. Im Falle von *Geschwindigkeit* gäbe es tatsächlich neben *groß, klein, hoch* und *niedrig* auch Adjektive wie *passend, angemessen* usw., die ebenfalls eine Art Metrik darstellen.
Es wäre wahrscheinlich besser zu fragen, wo bei häufigen Zweifelsfällen nachzusehen wäre. In solche einer Liste wäre *Geschwindigkeit* mit *hoch/groß* sicher enthalten.

Comment: Auch wenn ich die Erörterungen von Hubert Schölnast schön finde, hat diese Antwort die solideste Argumentation und bekommt den Zuschlag. Dank auch für den ngram-Link. Lt. diesem hat die *große Geschwindigkeit* kurz nach 1900 ihre weiteste (größte ;-) ) Verbreitung, *hohe Geschwindigkeit* hingegen um 1940 (wahrscheinlich handelt es sich um die *traurige* Geschwindigkeit von Projektilen).

Comment: Du leidest auch an der Gänsefüßchenkrankheit?

Answer (score 9):

Als Englischsprachiger, benutze ich oft [die DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r), um solche Verbindung zu finden. Zum Beispiel könntest du das Folgende suchen:

```
near($p=ADJ*, Geschwindigkeit, 2)
```

das alle Sätze im Korpus gibt, die höchstens zwei andere Wörter zwischen einem Adjektiv und "Geschwindigkeit" haben.

Du könntest auch verschiedene einzelne Suchen machen, und die Anzahl von Suchergebnis vergleichen:

```
"groß Geschwindigkeit" (138 Hits)
"hoch Geschwindigkeit" (129 Hits)
"schnell Geschwindigkeit" (1 Hit)
```

Da sind zahlreiche Einstellungen, die du ändern kannst, wie das Anfangs- und Enddatum oder welchen Referenzkorpus zu verwenden.

Du kannst [die Hilfseite](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpussuche) lesen, um mehr über die Syntax zu lernen. Die Syntax ist ziemlich stark, wann du sie richtig verwendest, aber es kann schwierig sein, zu lernen.

Answer (score 7):

Der deutsche Sprachraum ist zu groß und zu lebendig um solche Regeln festlegen zu können. Einzelne Adjektive haben in Bern, Wien, Dresden und Hamburg unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Ich bin Österreicher, geboren in Graz und lebe seit 17 Jahren in Wien. Wenn bei uns etwas "schön" ist, dann ist damit ausschließlich gefälliges Aussehen gemeint. Ich war recht erstaunt, als ich mal in einem Restaurant deutsche Touristen an einem Nachbartisch über "schönen Wein" reden hörte, wobei mit Schönheit ganz offenbar nicht das Aussehen des Weins, sondern sein guter Geschmack gemeint war.

"Hübsch" ist, meiner Wahrnehmung nach, in Österreich etwas weniger gebräuchlich als in Deutschland, aber vielleicht irre ich mich in diesem Punkt auch. Mit "hübsch" würde ich hauptsächlich Mädchen und junge Frauen bezeichnen. Auch Ziergegenstände (Vasen, Porzellanfiguren, kleine Wandbilder) können hübsch sein. Ein kleines Urlaubsstädtchen kann auch hübsch sein, und warum nicht auch eine Landschaft? Aber mit "hübsch" schwingt meiner Meinung nach auch immer etwas "kitschig" mit und es hat eine starke weibliche Note. Aus diesem Grund würden sich vermutlich auch viele Männer beleidigt fühlen, wenn man ihnen sagen würde sie wären hübsch. Aber eine Postkarten-Landschaft mit blühenden Fliederbüschen, und sanft geschwungenen Hügeln kann durchaus hübsch sein.

Ob eine Geschwindigkeit hoch oder groß ist, ist Geschmacksache. Auf keinen Fall ist sie aber schnell (habe ich leider auch schon gehört). Schnell ist der Gegenstand, der eine hohe/große Geschwindigkeit hat, aber nicht die Geschwindigkeit selbst. Sinngemäß dasselbe gilt für niedrige Geschwindigkeiten. Ein Auto, dass sich im Schritttempo bewegt, hat eine niedrige Geschwindigkeit oder man kann auch sagen, seine Geschwindigkeit sei klein. Die Geschwindigkeit ist aber niemals langsam, denn die Geschwindigkeit selbst bewegt sich ja nicht. Das Auto bewegt sich, daher ist das Auto langsam.

Comment: Schöne, durchaus auch hübsche Erörterung. Den Dialektaspekt hatte ich in meiner Frage gar nicht berücksichtigt. Aber der hat natürlich einen großen Einfluss auf die *richtige* oder *falsche* Verwendung von Adjektiven. Mehr als das: die Auswahl der Adjektive kann einen Teil des Charmes eines Dialekts ausmachen.

Comment: @Olaf: Wieso Dialektaspekt? Ich habe mich ausschließlich auf den regional unterschiedlichen Gebrauch der deutschen Hochsprache bezogen. Dialekte haben neben einen anderen Vokabular meist eine eigene Grammatik, die von der Grammatik der Hochsprache stark abweichen kann. Meine "Muttersprache", Oststeirisch, ein deutscher Dialekt, der im östlichen Teil der Steiermark gesprochen wird, kennt z.B. keinen Genitiv und nur eine Vergangenheitsform. Einige hochdeutsche Wörter (darunter auch "hübsch") kommen in diesem Dialekt gar nicht vor, dafür gibt es hunderte Vokabel, die der Hochsprache fehlen.

Comment: Die Abgrenzung von "Dialekt" zu "regional unterschiedlichem Gebrauch" finde ich logisch, hätte in meiner Unwissenheit aber alles, was irgendwo in Österreich gesprochen wird, als *Dialekt* bezeichnet. Dann würde ich also umformulieren: "Der Aspekt des regional unterschiedlichen Gebrauchs hat einen großen Einfluss...". Danke jedenfalls für die Ausführungen. Nebenbei, interessant, dass Oststeirisch den Genitiv nicht kennt. In bestimmten Gegenden hier in Berlin geht er ja gerade verloren...

Comment: Österreichisches Deutsch ist übrigens eine Varietät der deutschen Sprache, streng genommen also eine eigene selbstständige Sprache mit teilweise abweichender Grammatik und mit hunderten anderen Vokabeln. Während es für die in Deutschland gesprochene Varietät der deutschen Sprache kein offizielles Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache mehr gibt (der Duden hat diesen Status im Jahr 1996 verloren), existiert für österreichisches Deutsch nach wie vor ein amtliches Regelwerk, nämlich das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch), das vom Ministerium für Unterricht, Kunst und Kultur herausgegeben wird.

Comment: Wusste ich auch nicht, dass Österreich da nicht mitgezogen hat (nebenbei ist *ÖWB* ein Akronym, das irgendwie einen österreichischen Klangcharakter mit sich trägt).

Comment: Wo hat Österreich nicht mitgezogen? Als sich 1945 Österreich wieder von Deutschland trennte hörte für Österreich auch der Duden auf ein offizielles Standardwerk zu sein. In Deutschland dauerte es eben 51 Jahre länger bis man einer privaten Redaktion das Recht entzog zu bestimmen was richtiges Deutsch ist. Die Rechtschreibreform hat Österreich aber im vollen Umfang mitgemacht, was zur Folge hat, dass sich seit 1996 deutsches Deutsch und österreichisches Deutsch ähnlicher sind als vorher.

Comment: Aha, verstehe, es war mit der Abschaffung des Dudens also Vorreiter. Logisch.

Answer (score -1):

In einem guten Lexikon sollte stehen, was *groß* bedeutet, was *hoch* oder *lang*.

Eine andere Nachschlagmöglichkeit ist mir nicht bekannt, und Vollständigkeit ist wohl nicht gegeben.

Ich erinnere mich an Lehrer, die es tadelten, wenn man eine Person groß nannte, die 1,90 maß. Es wurde dann behauptet die Person sei lang aber nicht groß. Bei einem liegenden Körper, wenn ich die Länge des Sarges ermitteln soll, dann stimme ich zu - ansonsten halte ich *Körpergröße* nicht für falsch, nur weil auch Karl der Große als groß bezeichnet wird, groß also doppeldeutig ist.

Doppeldeutigkeiten hat man ja nun oft genug in der Sprache.

Comment: "Das Auto fuhr mit *schneller Geschwindigkeit* um die Kurve?" Klingt in meinen Ohren nicht richtig (der *lange Körper* des Lehrers aber auch nicht, auch wenn es offiziell "korrekt" ist). 
In einem Lexikon (oder wahrscheinlich eher einem Duden) stehen die Bedeutungen der Wörter, aber es bietet keine Zuordnung von Adjektiven zu Substantiven.

Comment: _Schnelle_ Geschwindigkeit würde ich persönlich nie sagen. Die Geschwindigkeit ist doch nicht schnell, sondern das Auto! Analog: Ein Bauteil kann winzig sein, oder von äußerst geringer Größe, aber nicht von winziger Größe.

Comment: @HendrikVogt You made the point. Die Geschwindigkeit ist: enorm, groß, hoch. Dennoch hat schnell [einen Eintrag](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/mit+schneller+Geschwindigkeit.html) in dict.cc. ... Was ich aber durchaus sagen würde, wäre "mit rasanter Geschwindigkeit". Keine Ahnung, warum ...

Comment: @user: Vielen Dank für das Beispiel "Temperatur"! Ja, genau: Es kann sehr heiß gewesen sein, oder die Temperatur kann auch sehr hoch gewesen sein. Aber würdest Du sagen "Gestern war die Temperatur sehr heiß"?

Comment: @Em1 "rasante Geschwindigkeit" halte ich für falsch, eher "rasante Fahrt". Als physikalische Einheit wird eine Geschwindigkeit eher hoch oder groß sein.

Comment: @harper Jap, das war auch der Pudels Kern meines Kommentars, dennoch klingt es - aus mir unerklärlichen Gründen - nicht falsch in meinem Ohr.

Comment: @user: gut `:-)`

Comment: @Olaf et.al. Mit 5 Jahren Abstand sehe ich meinen Fehler ein und habe die Passage gelöscht. Vielleicht lösche ich die Antwort auch noch insgesamt.